# send mail to bcc with mailgun with attached mpdf file

Tags: php, email, mpdf, mailgun

I'm sending attachment by following mpdf documentation [mpdf E-mail a PDF file](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=373), and i'm using mailgun API to send mails.

My Code is

```
$header = "From: ".'donotreply@'.$domain." \r\n";
            $header = "Subject: ".'My Subject'." \r\n";
            $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$solution->user->id."\"\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
            $header .= "--".$solution->user->id."\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= $body."\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= "--".$solution->user->id."\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"MySetSolution-".$solution->user->id.".pdf\"\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
            $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"MySetSolution-".$solution->user->id.".pdf\"\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
            $header .= "--".$solution->user->id."--";
            $mailgun->sendMessage($domain, array(
                    'from' => 'donotreply@'.$domain,
                    'to' => $email_address,
                    'subject' => 'My Subject',
                    'text' => $body 
                ),
                $header
            );
```

I hv tried both code

```
$header .= 'Bcc: $emailList';
```

and

```
'bcc' => $email_address
```

but unable to send mail for bcc recipients.

Thanks for any idea if possible.

Comment: Is there an error or does it fail silently?

Comment: nope.. there is no error when m adding $header .= 'Bcc: $emailList'; or 'bcc' => $email_address mail send to 'to' recipients but not to bcc recipients... if m sending without header its working for me but unable to attache pdf...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-sending.html#examples) you should be able to add attachments in an extra array:

```
$result = $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
    'to'      => 'foo@example.com',
    'cc'      => 'baz@example.com',
    'bcc'     => 'bar@example.com',
    'subject' => 'Hello',
    'text'    => 'Testing some Mailgun awesomness!',
    'html'    => '<html>HTML version of the body</html>'
), array(
    'attachment' => array('/path/to/file.txt', '/path/to/file.txt')
));
```

I don't think you can add them directly to the header, since the header is added before the body. It will probably result in an incorrect email.